# Project Suggestion for ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-ajax, projects

I was thinking that i wanted to gain some experience in the new asp.net mvc and some asp.net ajax. So i'd like to get some project suggestions that would suite for this!

Would maybe be fun to create a little bigger project on codeplex, like the storefront project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whatever you do, do not create an URL Shortening Service because that was [already my idea](http://codeplex.com/rick) :-P

Anyway, how about a [Twitter](http://www.twitter.com) Clone?

Answer (score 3):

Since you are using asp.net mvc any project that you take should fully utilize the benefits/features of asp.net mvc like

- TDD
- SEO Friendly URL's
- Proper separation of Model/Views and giving correct responsibility to the controllers.
- An ORM agnostic data layer
- Utilize membership provider (there's an equivalent available for asp.net mvc)
- and so on...

In this light, I suggest you take up a mini CMS, with jquery support.

Though you could take any other project as well, but it would be a good learning experience if you could utilize the above features (though some features are not specifically to deal with asp.net mvc).

Answer (score 2):

As we're nearing the holidays, why not make your own 'wish list' site? Add the ability to prioritize, multiple user accounts, etc. Sure, there are a lot of them out there on the web already, but you did say it was a learning project.

Comment: Oh i like this one very much!

Answer (score 1):

Create a project that will help YOU do or learn something in addition to MVC/AJAX.  For example, if you are interested in learning about requirements management, create an app which allows you to enter, managed, and trace requirement for a project.  Similarily, if you want to improve your project management skills, create a project management app.
By the same token, if you are a soduku nut, like me, create a soduku game.  The list is endless.  The trick is to do something the interests you.

Answer (score 0):

Well whatever is suggested I imagine there would be a lot of them out there already but some initial thoughts would be:

- Blog engine
- Todo list
- Wish list

Whatever you decide though look at some of the better options out there and try to pin point what makes them good and add extra functionality on top of that.

Answer (score 0):

Photo Gallery (although I think most people have given up on this and are using flickr)

Answer (score 0):

I think you should do a site that is some core for every other site you will be building in the future. Make login, news, blog... and a database design. Make models and controllers for them. And keep your db simple so you can extend it later with new features. That way you won't have to do this every time and be bored.

Answer (score 0):

- Travel booking site.
- Myspace/Facebook ripoff.

Answer (score 0):

I'm starting [an open source StackOverflow clone](http://github.com/ripper234/Stack-Underflow) in Asp.Net MVC - mainly to learn how to build websites :)